# Getting gerrit: set-account not found error

Tags: gerrit

I've created an account without email set and now there is no possibility to log in in this account. I've tried to use

```
ssh -v -p 29418 admin@host gerrit set-account --add-email user@host user
```

but I'm getting this

```
gerrit: set-account: not found
```

error. Do I need to install some other packages to have this?

Comment: And which version of gerrit are you using..?

Comment: Yup, the problem version. Thanks, it was installed like week ago and I havn't even thought it could be a problem.